# What is the operational cost for calculating an upper triangular times an upper triangular matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I am trying to count the number of operations in an upper triangular times upper triangular matrix calculation. So far I have come to the sum $n+3(n-1)+5(n-2)+7(n-3)+...+(1+(n-1)2)$, but I am unsure whether the $n$-th term is correct? What is the sum of this series, if it is correct? I do not get $O(n^{3})$ as expected, but this could be faulty algebra.

Comment: Does a multiplication of two entries count as one operation?

Comment: I assume you're doing this the standard way, since there are more clever methods that are $O(n^{2+\epsilon})$ for some $\epsilon<1$.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier yes, multiplication and additions are the operations I am trying to count (division and subtraction too but those won't be occurring here)

Comment: @MattSamuel yes standard matrix-matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your matrices $A,B$ assuming you're computing $AB$. Here is a matrix where each entry indicated how many times the corresponding entry in $B$ is going to be multiplied with an entry of $A$:

$$\pmatrix{1&1&1&\ldots &1\\0&2&2&\ldots&2\\0&0&3&\ldots&3\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\0&0&0&\ldots&n}$$
This gives $$\sum _{k=1}^n\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\,\,\,\text{ multiplications}$$
which is already $O(n^3).$ The subsequent additions are not going to be more costly than $O(n^3)$: each non-trivial entry in the product $AB$ (there are $O(n^2)$ such entries) is the sum of $n$ numbers, which means $n-1$ additions, times $O(n^2)$, so again $O(n^3)$.

Comment: Isn't the second entry in the matrix 2 since it's $a_{11}b_{12}+a_{12}b_{22}$, two multiplications?

Comment: @gjorche_petrov You misread what my matrix means. The entries are matched with entries of $B$, not $AB$.

Comment: Oh you're right, sorry!